Accommodation for 17-year-old in the UK
Can anyone suggest me hotels in the UK that accept a 17-year-old traveling alone, including London, Manchester, Birmingham. Please don't suggest youth hostels and premier inn, they won't accept, I already checked.
If anyone knows then please give me proper details and hotels or hostels, anything.

When I was 17 and had to book a hotel at Leeds, I think my father had to be involved in some way (can't recall exactly what - perhaps some authorisation?) but otherwise went smoothly. Also what is this for? How long are you planning to stay?

What is the purpose of your trip to the UK (ie the purpose you stated in your visa application)? Typically someone who has a UK Child Visitor visa would likely be staying eg with relatives/friends, or perhaps in pre-arranged study-related accommodation.

Be careful. From your other questions You've already had a close call in Britain, and now you have a refusal in Mexico and another in Paris. You're starting to look desperate. If you fetch up in London again now, even with confirmed accommodation, it wouldn't be surprising if immigration took more interest in you. In a few months your age will no longer be a problem for accommodation. You might do well to wait.

Listen can i take transit from london heathrow because when i went there i saw that i can transit from there , is there any way that i reach heathrow after that i book a new ticket and go any other country where i can go with my passport ??

@JasbirMalik Whether you can transit in LHR is a completely different topic to accommodation booking for a 17yo in the UK. You need to ask a new question if you would like an answer.

The Youth Hostel Association of England and Wales explicitly says that anyone over the age of 16 is permitted to stay in their accommodation unaccompanied. If you tried to do this and failed there may be another reason they would not accept your booking.
Note that there are many accommodations that call themselves "youth hostels" but are not part of the YHA. You maybe tried booking a hostel that was not. Go to the website above and look for a list of their hostels and call them specifically.
There are YHA hostels in London and Manchester but not Birmingham. However you should be aware that they are extremely popular and fill up very quickly.

Some of the independent (or other chain) hostels may also accept under 18s but finding those is harder still.

Haven't been there in >10 years but I remember the one in Rotherhithe to be quite large.

The ones outside big cities are probably better, but the London one will be popular, the same way all cheap accommodation in London is popular.

Youth Hostel accommodation may not be deemed suitable by UK Immigration for someone travelling on a Child Visitor visa

@Traveller Why do you think that would be? And if it was the case then why would any hotel be considered suitable accommodation?

@DJClayworth Because as an unaccompanied minor, the Child Visa rules specify certain requirements that a YHA (or indeed a hotel, which is presumably why the OP can’t book one) would likely not want to / be able to meet eg name of person the child visitor is staying with. I suspect the UK Border Official mentioned in the OP’s previous question probably knew that the OP would likely not be able to find a hotel willing to take their booking. I’m sure 10s of 000s of 17yo stay in UK youth hostels every year but not very many of them try to enter using a Child Visitor visa.

But if no hotel or hostel would satisfy immigration why wouldn't they just say that? Immigration phoned the OPs booked hotel (see other question) to check whether a 17 year old was allowed to stay? Why would immigration do that if there was zero chance of it being acceptable?

@DJClayworth I didn’t say there’s zero chance of a hotel or YH being accepted. I said there are rules on the suitability of accommodation for minors. I guess the Officer phoned the hotel personally as part of the OP’s landing interview, to check its policy because  many/most hotels don’t accept bookings from minors, and the IO would know that. IDK if UK Immigration would accept a booking in a YH, but the rules support a duty of care towards an unaccompanied minor entering the UK. The OP would’ve had to give accommodation info in the visa application,it’d be simpler to stay there, surely.

Brother what do you think i didn't tried anything i went there and tried full night i contacted every hostel hotel airbnb but they just told that we can't accept under any circumstances but there is a hotel in scotland but i went to london that's why

@Traveller OK, now I've read the other conditions for under-18s I see what you mean.

@JasbirMalik As Traveller says, you seem to have had other problems finding accommodation that satisfied the terms of your visa. In general the YHA does accept unaccompanied 17 year olds, but they may not have satisfied your immigration conditions.

To ensure we provide safe and suitable accommodation for everyone, children under the age of 16 must be accompanied by a person who is 18 years or older. Children at the age of 12 and over can stay in public dormitories if accompanied by an adult, who they checked into the Hostel with. Children under the age of 12 are not permitted to stay in public dormitory accommodation and should be booked into a private room. Children who are ages 16 or over may stay in any accommodation. Groups of guests of mixed genders, who wish to stay in the same room, must book private accommodation.

@JasbirMalik Yes, that's exactly the quote from their rules. As you see, they allow unaccompanied people over 16.

But i asked hotels and hostels for Alone.

And a Youth Hostel Association hostel would have accepted your booking, unless they had some other reason to exclude you. A different kind of youth hostel might not. Not all hostels belong to the YHA.

@JasbirMalik To be completely clear "unaccompanied" means "alone". The YHA accepts 17 year-olds alone.
